# Is there a way to capture a picture by the iPhone via Browser?

Tags: iphone, image, ios, browser

Can i capture Pictures via Browser with the iPhone?

Or what is the easyest way? which API?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this isn't currently possible (as of iOS v4.2) - the only way to currently interact with the camera, etc. is via a full-blown iOS app.

The only additional capabilities that are provided beyond a "normal" browser are JavaScript events to capture touch related actions.

Comment: Couldn't he write a hybrid app that makes use of webviews to simulate browser behavior and the camera API?

Comment: @Geoff Baum - Yes, that's definitely a possibility. :-)